# I want to convert the last two elements of a list into a nested list in python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a list `['111be867d567bc', 2, 0, 1808, 1403]` and want to convert the last two elements into a nested list like this:

```
['111be867d567bc', 2, 0, [1808, 1403]]
```

Comment: Have you tried something so far that you may want to show?

Answer (score 5):

Good use case for slicing;

```
foo = ['111be867d567bc', 2, 0, 1808, 1403]
foo[-2:] = [foo[-2:]]
print(foo)
```

Outputs;

```
['111be867d567bc', 2, 0, [1808, 1403]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the `list`

```
l = ['111be867d567bc', 2, 0, 1808, 1403]

l[:-2] + [l[-2:]]
>>> ['111be867d567bc', 2, 0, [1808, 1403]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that :

```
myList=['111be867d567bc', 2, 0, 1808, 1403]
mySubList=[myList[-2:]]
myList=myList[:-2]
myList.append(mySubList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the slice `:` (to pick the bits and pieces you want from a list) and concatenate `+` to glue lists together.

Demo:

```
In [1]: mylist = ['111be867d567bc', 2, 0, 1808, 1403]

In [2]: mylist
Out[2]: ['111be867d567bc', 2, 0, 1808, 1403]

In [3]: mylist2 = mylist[:-2] + [mylist[-2:]]

In [4]: mylist2
Out[4]: ['111be867d567bc', 2, 0, [1808, 1403]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['111be867d567bc', 2, 0, 1808, 1403] 
y = x[-2:]
x = x[:-2]
x = x+[y]
```

x should now look like this

```
['111be867d567bc', 2, 0, [1808, 1403]]
```